# How to pass custom function to dataframe.apply with parameters other than row(axis=1)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm working on script that automatically generates ***full file path*** column using **df.apply()** as below.

```
def generate_filepath(row):
    all_files = os.listdir(files_dir)
    if row['FileName'] not in all_files:
        return None
    value = os.path.join(files_dir, row['FileName'])
    return value


csv_df['FilePath'] = csv_df.apply(generate_filepath, axis=1)
```

I had to declare **files_dir** as a global variable and then use it in the function. Is there any other I can pass it as an argument along with df.apply?
Kindly help me with good suggestions

Comment: Have you tried `def generate_filepath(row, files_dir)` and then using `csv_df.apply(generate_filepath, axis=1, files_dir='whatever')` ? Any kwargs not consumed by `.apply` itself are passed to the applied function.

Comment: will try that right now and let you know

Comment: It also qeems a waste doing `os.listdir` for every item if it's always going to be the same filedir...

Comment: @JonClements I tried and it worked and you suggest passing the os.listdir once to the function right?

Comment: Ahh... coldspeed's found a duplicate for you... you might even not want to bother with apply in this case - get your listing once... and then use `np.where(...)` with suitable criteria to create your new column...

Comment: @JonClements Thanks Jon will try that too!

Comment: @JonClements to be fair, op's question is pretty common. There are lots of way in python to solve it. I do not know why I was downvoted for suggesting currying as the duplicate was for currying

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you curry your function?

https://www.python-course.eu/currying_in_python.php

or add another argument?

Edit: Jon Clements answer is better than mine